# How Do I Hide a Class from Other Subsystems

Tags: c++

I can make the class private and write it inside a public class. Then no other sub system will have access to it. **How do I create it in such a way that it does not have to be written inside the same public class.**

Comment: Please provide more clarity, The q is not clear itself, also if you can provide some small sample that'd help us help you

Comment: The question seems very clear to me. What is not clear is that "q" in your comment, I am assuming it means question, but it could be anything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can put it in a separate .cpp file and give it no header file. This has the effect that you can't access it from other C++ code.

Here is an example:

*worker.h*

```
#pragma once
class Worker{
    //some class definition
};
```

*worker.cpp*

```
#include "worker.h"
class Hidden{
    //some class definition
};
//implementation of Worker class which uses Hidden class
```

*some_other_file.cpp*

```
//if you only include the header, the class Hidden does not exist
#include "worker.h"
```

**How do I compile this?**

```
g++ -c worker.cpp -o worker.o
g++ some_other_file.cpp  worker.o -o some_other_file
```

Answer (score 4):

There is no concept of access specifiers at type level in C++. You can achieve keeping classes private in two ways:

- nested class inside another class, as you already mentioned
- no public constructor; if a class does not have an accessible constructor it cannot be instantiated.